# Play video when clicking a button on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, button, video

I have a video from my assets I want to be played when a button is clicked on my Android Flutter app, but without having the normal actions like pause, play...etc. And I will add a "skip" button on the video that will navigate to another page, is that all possible?

Comment: Hi @Nooni and welcome to StckOverflow. In order to help the community understand your problem and help you back, you might want to look at how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can play video in Background and add skip button on it.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35caowA4EMc